# Order of each element in a symmetry group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

In abstract algebra, the order of an element in a cyclic group is defined as the smallest positive integer such that that element to the power of that integer yields the group's identity. However, why is the definition of order seem to be different for symmetry groups? For them, the definition of order is the number of times that it fits on to itself during a full rotation of 360 degrees. Or are those definitions the same?

Comment: They are the same because the identity in a symmetric group is rotation by $2n\pi$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Rotation by a multiple of $360^{\large{\circ}}$ **is** the identity in any group of transformations of a Euclidean space, so the two definitions are the same.

Comment: These definitions are just the same.

Comment: The elements of such a symmetry group are the transformations which take the object back to itself. So, if you have a regular pentagon, a fifth of a rotation clockwise will have to be done five times to bring the pentagon back to how it was, and the pentagon will have rotated $360$ degrees. A rotation of two fifths of a turn will also have to be done five times to get the pentagon back to how it was. But in that case the pentagon will have rotated $720$ degrees. The point is how many times does it take to get back where you started, ie, the identity.

Comment: @RobArthan I see, so the order for a square rotation of 90 degrees is 4 since (4)(90) = 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of an element $a$ in *any* group $G$ is defined to be the least positive integer $n$ such that $a^n=e$, where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

For a cyclic group $C=\langle a\rangle$, the identity element is $e=a^0$.

For a symmetry group $S$ consisting some isometries $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, the identity element is the identity map $x\mapsto x$. It is easily seen that rotate by $2n\pi$ ($n\in\mathbb{Z}$) is the same as the identity map.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. So the order of a square rotation of $270$ degrees is $4$, because $(270)(4) = (3)(360)$, and so $270$ has to be multiplied four times to produce a multiple of $360$?

Comment: @numericalorange Yes, you're right.